# How to create a OData List?

Tags: android, odata, sapui5

I want to create a OList, so that every position opened a new OList if I tap on it. At this moment I have following code:

```
function readCustomerSuccessCallback(data, response) {

        var citems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var citem = new sap.m.StandardListItem(
                    {
                    type: "Active",
                    tap : readProducts(data.results[i].STATION_ID),
                    title: data.results[i].CUSTOMER_NAME,
                    description: data.results[i].STATION_ID
                    });
            citems.push(citem);
        }
        var oList = new sap.m.List({
            headerText : "Customers",
            setGrowingScrollToLoad: true,
            items : citems,
            press: function(e) {
            console.log(oList.getSelectedItems());
            }
        });
        oList.placeAt("content"); // place model onto UI
    }
    function readProducts(category) {
        console.log("read request started");
        startTime = new Date();

        if (!haveAppId()) {
        return;
        }

        sURL = myUrl;
        var oHeaders = {};
        oHeaders['Authorization'] = authStr;
        //oHeaders['X-SMP-APPCID'] = appCID;    //this header is provided by the logon plugin

        var request = {
            headers : oHeaders,
            requestUri : sURL,
            method : "GET"
            };
        OData.read(request, readProductsSuccessCallback, errorCallback);
    }
```

The function read CustomerSuccesCAllback creates a OList,and if I tap on a field of this list, I want that a new List shows up. For the second step is the function readproducts responsible.

With this code it doesnt work. It shows me not the customers, but only theyre details.
Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change in `readCustomerSuccessCallback`:**

```
    tap: function(e){
            readProducts(this.getDescription),
         }
 //this will stop invoking the function while defining your items
```